# Map reduce word count

Tags: hive, mapreduce, word-count

How to search for the specific word using either

1) Map Reduce WC program - Java code or
2) Word count with Hive

Eg: below is my file

```
Hello my name is Jammy
Jammy is the best
Jammy likes football
```

I want to search how many times the word "Jammy" appeared.. Please suggest

Comment: as you know hive follows column structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please find word count  example with Integration Test .

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/word-count-map-reduce

You can add a filter in the Map phase for, if you only want a specific word in the output.

```
 if (tokenizer.nextToken().equals("Jammy")){
          word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
 }
```